# How to reshape a picture numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matrix, reshape

I have an RGB picture with a shape (640,480,3)

I need a shape of (3,640*480)

I use

```
picture.reshape(3,(picture.shape[0]*picture.shape[1]))
```

and it gives the expected shape but with wrong data inside. I need each channel in a single row.

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshaping does not change the order of the data. Try serialising the spatial dimensions first and then transposing:

```py
>>> by_channel = picture.reshape(-1, 3).transpose()  # or .T for short
>>> by_channel.shape  # Correct shape?
(3, 311040)
>>> np.all(by_channel[0] == picture[..., 0].ravel())  # Correct data?
True
```

The `.transpose()` operation is its own inverse, so to transform it back, simply do:

```py
>>> _picture = by_channel.T.reshape(picture.shape)
>>> np.all(_picture == picture)
True
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me how to transform it back now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the use of the reshape function:

The documentation is:

```
np.reshape(array,shape)
```

which returns the array. The problem with your code is that you have listed the elements wrong, which makes the computer think that you are reshaping the number 3 into shape(640*480).

The correct code in this scenario is:

```
picture = np.reshape(picture,(3,640*480))
```

Comment: I call picture.reshape, not np.reshape

Comment: @Victor Sim: `array.reshape()` is one of the few NumPy functions (or the only one?) that accepts shape parameters unpacked as individual arguments, so lojevas301's usage of the reshape function was correct in that sense.

Comment: I do understand that, but I believe that np.reshape can solve the problem in just one line, so I therefore put this as my answer.